# Documenting Kotlin code: How to create a table?

Tags: kotlin, code-documentation, kdoc

I have read this article about [documenting Kotlin code](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html) and [this article](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) as well. I tried this code:

```
 /**
 * | First Header  | Second Header |
 * | ------------- | ------------- |
 * | Content Cell  | Content Cell  |
 * | Content Cell  | Content Cell  |
 */
```

And this:

```
 /**
 * This is a regular paragraph.
 *
 * <table>
 * <tr>
 * <td>Foo</td>
 * </tr>
 * </table>
 *
 * This is another regular paragraph.
 */
```

I also tried to remove `*` chars:

```
 /**
  | First Header  | Second Header |
  | ------------- | ------------- |
  | Content Cell  | Content Cell  |
  | Content Cell  | Content Cell  |
 */
```

But nothing happened. Documentation is important when we write a lot of code.

So, do you know how to create a table in Kotlin documentation?